# Binding table with multiple sources

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loopbackjs

I want to create a table with this spec :

```
                        | [Test Name]   | [Test Name]   |
student name            | [coefficient] | [coefficient] |
[Name of 1st student]   | [Result]      | [Result]      |
[Name of 2nd student]   | [Result]      | [Result]      |
etc.
```

I have three table in my database :

```
    Student (studentId, name), 
    Test (testId, testName, coefficient), 
    Result (resultNumber, studentId, testId).
```

I don't know how can I link in angular the result, student and test, and show the good result with the good student in the good row.

And I want make editable and automatically save field with [Test Name], [coefficient] and [Result]. I know how to do that, it's just to explain all the context.

I have not find example like this so if you have, I am really interesting.

Sorry for english mistake, I am french.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: so you are trying to create a pivot table?

Comment: Yes, seems to be something like that. After read your answer, I search for that, I think it's a good idea. But do you know how can I get the id of student when student is like that : <td>{{student.name}}</td>